# I want to make a new SSD Card my boot drive: Is there a good program on Ubuntu for that?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

So, I'm planning to get an SSD card soon and make it my boot drive, as I've heard that can make your computer boot much faster. I also want to try to leave my old HDD in as a secondary storage drive. Is there a good program someone can recommend to me to transfer the boot data onto the SDD?

Edit: I want to try to keep my current install of Ubuntu and just move it over to the new SSD card.

Comment: I just use the ubuntu installer on a USB.  Use the something else option, make a small(300MBs) EFI partition and a 30 to 40 GBs /root partition or bigger, on SSD.  Make a /home partition on hard drive as big as you want.  If data on HD you want to keep, backup first.

Comment: Above comment for a new install.  If you are thinking of using the install you have now and copying over, that is totally different.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the current install and just try to move the boot over.

Comment: I don't know why bother. What's wrong with the current boot files location? Why move them? Having boot files on an SD card would not provide any advantage.

Comment: Mostly because my computer is old and pretty slow, so I would like to upgrade its boot time. Plus, I've heard that SSD cards can be more reliable that hard disk drives, and my HDD is really old.

Comment: That is a major misconception. Moving boot files to an SD card will not make an old computer any faster. Consider replacing that old HDD with something more modern and efficient.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Are you thinking of a SD card or a SSD drive?

Comment: I was thinking of an SSD drive.

Comment: In that case I would go with new install.  Saying your computer is old, just check to make sure it can use a SSD.  Most computers with sata drives can, but expected speed might not as fast.  Be faster than HD.

Comment: I used a system scanner to be sure that the SSD I was looking at would be compatible with my computer.+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make the same partition table on SSD like your HDD (user GParted or similar on GUI oder fdisk on console)
2. boot from a live cd with old HDD and new SSD connected to your system
3. mount the new SSD and old HDD (check the devices before with "sudo fdisk -l")

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/new
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/new

   sudo mkdir /mnt/old
   sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/old
   ```
4. sync you data with `rsync` from old to new

   ```
   sudo rsync --stats --progress --numeric-ids -axAhHSP  /mnt/old/ /mnt/new
   ```
5. search the new UUIDs for your new partitions on your SSD with

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```
6. edit `/etc/fstab` on your new SSD with the UUIDs for "/" and "SWAP"
7. chroot your new SSD

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
   sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc 
   sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot/efi 
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
8. update grub (please check that `/dev/sda` is your SSD! or change the device name!)

   ```
   update-grub2
   grub-install /dev/sda
   ```

   ```
   update-grub
   ```
9. finish, you can exit and reboot with your old system on your new SSD

After this, you can mount your old HDD wherever you want in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Raspberry Pi ssd creation tool.  It has never failed me yet.

Comment: It's a great tool.